# How do you pass information through viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I currently have a button on my settings page which is called `Test Database` 
My goal is to change the reading registry when that button is clicked, it'll read from dummy Database. 
The issue I'm having is that it's on two difference .cs files and was wondering how do I pass information to one another.

```
public static FBContext Get()
{
    if (ConnectionString == null)
    {
        var openSubKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE");
        if (openSubKey != null)
        {
            var registryKey = openSubKey.OpenSubKey("TestSoftware");
            if (registryKey != null)
               ConnectionString =  registryKey.GetValue("ctx").ToString();
        }
     }
     return new FBContext(ConnectionString);
}
```

I want to change the inner IF statement to something like this, where there will be a `Global` bool variable `TestDatabase` that can be accessible through different views.

```
if (registryKey != null)
{
    If(TestDataBase == false)        
        ConnectionString =  registryKey.GetValue("ctx").ToString();        
    else
        ConnectionString = "Test Database String";
}
```

Comment: Is this ASP.Net Webforms? MVC?

Comment: "clicked to a dummy database"? What does the register has to do with a database?

Comment: The registry key has connection string details. @CommuSoft

Comment: Why not use app.config or web.config for your connection settings? Having worked with pulling data from the registry it can be a nightmare to manage with lots of installs. Especially if someone has the ability to start editing their registry

Comment: I definitely understand that, but it wasn't my approach. Just building ontop of existing. @DavidShorthose

Comment: Ah ok. I understand. I would seriously consider changing if it's possible. As to answer your question if you have the value already contained outside this then just pass that value in at initialisation and then if the system needs to use it then it can access it internally and means you aren't dependant on any other code to access this.

Comment: Nope.  This is why we have dependency injection.  Use that.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you have to reconsider the organization of you application in layers or services.

At least you must have a separation between presentation and service classes: Viewmodels (in ASP.Net, Webforms or MVC ) should not know about database access details.

The usual way of implement that separation is using dependency injection.

Said that, you can have a static class DBConfiguration as

```
public static class DBConfiguation
    {
        string _connection = null;

        public string Connection {
            get
            {
                if (_connection == null)
                {
                    //... you load code
                }
                return _connection;
            }
            set
            {
                _connection = value;
            }

        }
    }
```

and access always to connection string using that class.